# ssrs report parameter passing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

i am calling ssrs report through c# using reportviewer, i have to pass two parameter

```
DateTime reportFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["datefrom"].ToString());
DateTime reportTDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["dateto"].ToString());


{report viewer code}

List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("FROMDATE", reportFromDate));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("TODATE", reportTDate));

{report viewer code}
```

its showing invalid argument error in the parameters.Add lines

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("FROMDATE", reportFromDate));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("TODATE", reportTDate));

Comment: Are you sure your `ReportParameter` type has a constructor takes 2 parameter (string, DateTime) ?

Comment: the report paramter is taking only (string, string[]), so my questionis how to pass date time

Comment: You can't pass `DateTime` as a parameter where your `ReportParameter` expects a string array.